# TextField only accept numeric and store in ArrayList<Double>

Tags: java, list

I have a textField which only accept numeric number in two decimal places and I want it store in ArrayList....How can I do that?

```
private JTextField textField;
    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(126, 105, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    NumberFormat numberFormat =  NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
    decimalFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
    textField = new JFormattedTextField(decimalFormat);
    textField.setColumns(15); 

     double b = textField.getText(); //Change type of b to string    

      ArrayList<Double> myVector=new ArrayList<Double>(); 

    myVector.add(b);
```

Comment: You did it right. What's the problem?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `b` is a double type, whereas `getText` doesn't return a double.

You need to change it to double before you assign it to that variable.

```
double b = 0;
try
{
  b = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText().toString());     
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  System.out.println("Invalid number!");
}
ArrayList<Double> myVector=new ArrayList<Double>(); 
myVector.add(b);
```

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)  what it mean?

Comment: Your textField is empty. Try entering some value.

Comment: I have entering some value , bu still get the same error

Comment: I get invalid number .Why ?

Comment: Because the value which you enter is invalid and the default value is appended.

Comment: 100.50 still consider invalid?

Comment: Yes, if your Locale settings use a comma as decimal mark. Try `Locale.US` instead of `Locale.getDefault()`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can restrict the input to have a fixed number of decimal places. But you have an option to verify the input and format it into the required format. You can use a Regex pattern to check the format of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your String from the `TextField` is valid, then do whatever you need to do. Regex would do well, if you want a specific number of digits.
This example checks for a number with *exactly* two decimals.

```
    String someNumber = "1234.12";  // your TextField value goes here

    if (someNumber.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?")) {
        System.out.println("valid");
        double doubleNumber = Double.parseDouble(someNumber);
        System.out.println(doubleNumber);
        // more code
    } else {
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
```